# How to set up Scrapy, Anaconda 3 and PyCharm 2018.3.5

Tags: scrapy, pycharm, anaconda, python-3.7

I have just started experimenting with PyCharm 2018.3.5, Anaconda 2018.12, but I have a lot of difficulty of setting it up with Scrapy. Therefore, I would like to ask you all for some assistance, in order to get things up and running. I am following the following [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) in order to test whether Scrapy works with PyCharm and Anaconda. This does not seem to be the case. The setup is done on a Windows 10 machine with the latest updates.

I have also included every step of the installation process and hopefully, you would be able to point where I went wrong.

1. Installing Anaconda on the default location.
2. Install PyCharm on the default location.
3. Install OpenSSL (for this version of PyCharm, you need to install this apparently in order for it to find packages; link: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
4. I proceed to start PyCharm and create my first Scrapy project, using the follwing settings:
   [image: PyCharm settings]
5. I proceed to wait until PyCharm is done with everything and then I open Anaconda Navigator, which I will use to install **scrapy** and **beautifulsoup4**. The following image shows the result:
   [image: Anaconda environment with Scrapy]
6. In PyCharm, Scrapy is also visible:
   [image: Scrapy in PyCharm]
7. Next, I go into Explorer and navigate to `C:\Users\admin Man\PycharmProjects\Test` (Notice that this is the same directory as in step 4).
8. So, first I tried using Command Prompt, but this fails:

[image: Command prompt failure]

I read that this is because the Anaconda Prompt does something with the paths. So I used the following command in Anaconda Prompt.

[image: Anaconda Prompt Scray startproject]

**A small question in between. I was wondering how I can make it work in cmd.exe what I did in Anaconda prompt without activating an environment**. I think answering this question would give me a better understanding in what Anaconda prompt does.

9. This succeeds, now I have the following directory:

[image: Directory of Scrapy project]

10. So I just followed the tutorial online and created the following spider.

[image: Spider]

11. Then I set up the following configuration

[image: Configuration]

I tried to run with python console and emulate options, but that all fails. I checked whether I have the request package and I have request 2.21.0.

The error I got is the following:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\python.exe C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/Test/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py crawl quotes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/Test/Lib/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scrapy
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\_monkeypatches.py", line 20, in <module>
    import twisted.persisted.styles  # NOQA
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\twisted\persisted\styles.py", line 21, in <module>
    from twisted.python.compat import _PY3, _PYPY
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import unicode
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\compat.py", line 605, in <module>
    from http import cookiejar as cookielib
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.headers import Headers
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from w3lib.url import safe_url_string
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\w3lib\url.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import pathname2url, url2pathname
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 160, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone how I can fix it? In addition, I also tried setting up the working directory to something else, but I don't know to where, I tried of course the project directory.

Actually, I can find the module that it seems to be missing (see below):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, I have found the answer. This problem relates to PyCharm 2018.3.5. I guess I need to wait until PyCharm 2019.1 is released.

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002972999-Running-Scrapy-Conda-configuration-throws-error-but-running-in-Anaconda-terminal-doesn-t?input_string=PyCharm%2C%20Anaconda3%20and%20Scrapy